# Problema con div (columnas)

Tags: css, imagen, div

estoy modificando una pagina creada por un compañero. El problema es que antes tenia 2 columnas y 1 sola fila. Solo hay imagenes ahi. Asi tengo el codigo.

```
        <div class="row oo">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="inner-img"><img src="img/imagen-1.jpg"></div></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="inner-img"><img src="img/imagen-2.jpg"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row oo">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="inner-img"><img src="img/imagen-3.jpg"></div></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="inner-img"><img src="img/imagen-4.jpg"></div></div>
        </div>
```

El problema es que me aparece una sola imagen, por fila, y tendrian que aparecer 2 imagenes por fila en cada columna.

Comment: Pero sí te aparecen visibles las dos columnas? Qué resolución tiene la pantalla en que lo estás testeando?

Answer (score 1):

no se cual sea la resolución de tu pantalla, pero recuerda que bootstrap funciona a través de un sistema de rejillas que tiene 12 columnas, adicional a esto ya tiene definido sus puntos de quiebre entre resolución y resolución, entonces si tu pantalla es pequeña y entra entre las resoluciones de las clases xs ó sm, tú tienes definido que ocupen las 12 columnas cada imagen y como no hay mas columnas la que sigue la pone debajo. Entonces puedes decirle que sea 6 y 6 solamente y ya cabrían las dos en una sola fila.

```css
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row oo">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="inner-img"><img src="http://www.infotechnology.com/export/sites/revistait/img/internet/2015/07/21/epictierra.png_765980715.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="inner-img"><img src="http://www.infotechnology.com/export/sites/revistait/img/internet/2015/07/21/epictierra.png_765980715.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row oo">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="inner-img"><img src="http://www.infotechnology.com/export/sites/revistait/img/internet/2015/07/21/epictierra.png_765980715.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="inner-img"><img src="http://www.infotechnology.com/export/sites/revistait/img/internet/2015/07/21/epictierra.png_765980715.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```